# cannot import name 'BaseRequest'

Tags: python, flask, aws-sam

I am building a flask lambda application using AWS SAM and my requirements.txt file looks like follows
requests
contentful
flask-lambda
numpy
Recently the flask lambda libraries were updated and since then i am getting the following error whenever i run the lambda function:

```
{"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'app': cannot import name 'BaseRequest' from 'werkzeug.wrappers' (/var/task/werkzeug/wrappers/__init__.py)", "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError", "requestId": "f6e80202-e6ca-4335-9b3c-f15b3a6496c1", "stackTrace": []}[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'app': cannot import name 'BaseRequest' from 'werkTraceback (most recent call last):/wrappers/__init__.py)
```

Comment: see https://github.com/sivel/flask-lambda/issues/13 and https://github.com/sivel/flask-lambda/pull/14

Comment: @timotheecour that does not resolve the issue, i then get a "keyerror" message after making that fix

Answer (score 5):

I fixed it by downgrading the package to Werkzeug==2.0.3 in requirements.txt

Answer (score 0):

`pip install werkzeug --upgrade`

then

`pip install flask --upgrade`